# Is indentation not always needed in a While Loop?

Tags: python, validation, input, while-loop, indentation

Why does this code work? I thought I should indent everything in a loop, but if I do, the loop breaks off. Instead, if I DON'T indent, it works. Seem backwards to me. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

P.S. Obviously I'm a total noob.

```py
#This works
def choose_team():
       
    answer = ""
    
    while not (answer == "X" or answer == "O"):
        answer = input("Choose X eller O: ")
        
    if answer == "X":
        return("You are player 1")
    if answer == "O":
        return("You are player 2")
    else:
        return("Pick X or O ffs, moron")
```

```
#This DOES NOT WORK! 
def choose_team():
       
    answer = ""
    
    while not (answer == "X" or answer == "O"):
        answer = input("Choose X eller O: ")

        if answer == "X":
            return("You are player 1")
        if answer == "O":
            return("You are player 2")
        else:
            return("Pick X or O ffs, moron")
```

Comment: Both implementations contain bugs. First example three silent bugs: `else` is not reachable,  second `if` should be the `else` branch, the error message is never printed for unwanted inputs. Second example should not `return` in `else` branch.

Comment: Suggest to run the code in this great platform to see (and debug) it - https://pythontutor.com/  next time.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain, but my english is not good, sorry!

- the first thing you need to know that the while ends when the condition is met in this case != (answer == "X" or answer == "O"),
- In the first case, it works, and when the at the end loop you will go to the if condition, but you don't need the else, because the answer will be "X" or "O".
- When you need to use 2 or more conditions, you should use

```
if condition 1
elif condition 2
else
```

-The second thing to know, is when you return a function, you stop the process.
Then when you return and validate the answer in your function, the while is automatically stopped.
eg.

```
def numbers(num):
 print(1)
 if num == 1:
   return "end"
 print(2)
 if num == 2:
   return "end"
 print(3)
 if num == 3:
   return "end"
```

- The second function, also works, but the while is useless, it's the same if you write the function whitout the while. It's because, you always return something, regardless of the answer.